# En SQL Server 2008, requiero disminuir parte decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select (select (select(select sum(paquetes) from koc4 where Material = '1000230')*((select AVG (convert(decimal (10,2),(Prom_lote)))as prom_lot 
from QM where Material = '1000230')/1000) )-((select (select sum(paquetes) from koc4 where Material = '1000230')
*((select convert (decimal (10,2),Peso_bruto) from Maestro where Material = '1000230')/1000) )))
/((select (select sum(paquetes) from koc4 where Material = '1000230')*((select [Peso neto]
 from Maestro where Material = '1000230')/1000)))*100 as percentaje
```

Me arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
percentaje
1.64220000000002
```

Quisiera que solo mostrara 1.64

Comment: ¿Has probado con `ROUND()`?

Comment: No lo he probado, lo hago y te cuento, gracias

Comment: Gracias, me funciono con:  select cast(1.6422000000 as decimal(10,2))

Comment: miguel: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como menciono [@fedorqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui), utilizando `ROUND` es posible. Ahora bien, para lograr que reduzca(o trunque) los números, el tipo de dato tiene que tener posiciones decimales.

Por ejemplo, si redondeamos un `decimal` sin posiciones decimales, este nos lo redondearía:

```
  SELECT ROUND( CAST(1.64220000000002 AS decimal), 2)
  // Imprime 2
```

Ahora bien, si le indicamos las posiciones al tipo de dato nos reducirá la cantidad de decimales y nos dará el resultados esperado:

```
select  ROUND(cast(1.6422000000 as decimal(10,2)), 2)
// imprime 1.64
```

Asi que en tu caso, asegúrate de convertir porcentaje con las posiciones decimales.

Answer (score 1):

No hay necesidad de hacer un `ROUND`. Solo necesitas hacer el `CAST` especificando la cantidad de decimales que quieres:

```
select cast(1.6422000000 as decimal(10,2)) -- devuelve 1.64
select cast(1.6472000000 as decimal(10,2)) -- devuelve 1.65
```

De hecho, no tiene mucho sentido aplicar el `ROUND` una vez que ya hemos reducido las decimales a 2, ya que sería entonces demasiado tarde para aplicar el `ROUND`. Si acaso, la forma correcta hubiera sido de aplicar el `ROUND` primero, y luego el `CAST`.

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó con: select cast(1.6422000000 as decimal(10,2))